# excluding non-ascii characters in python

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters

I have a script which uses a dictionary to decrypt an encrypted message, the problem is the decryption process produces a lot of junk (a.k.a non-ascii) characters. Here is my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import os

BLOCK_SIZE = 32

PADDING = '{'

# Encrypted text to decrypt
encrypted = "WI4wBGwWWNcxEovAe3p+GrpK1GRRQcwckVXypYlvdHs="

DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

adib = open('words.txt')
for line in adib.readlines():
    secret = line.rstrip('\n')
    if (secret[-1:] == "\n"):
        print "Error, new line character at the end of the string. This will not match!"
    elif (len(secret) >= 32):
        print "Error, string too long. Must be less than 32 characters."
    else:
        # create a cipher object using the secret
        cipher = AES.new(secret + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(secret) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING)

        # decode the encoded string 
        decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encrypted)
        print decoded+"\n"
```

what I have thought of so far is converting `decoded` string into Ascii then exclude non-ascii characters but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you precise a "words.txt" file content example please

Comment: It contains common words, but here are some words

Comment: `the
and
One
Piece
Episode
Chapter
Pirates
Arc
The
Edit
Volume
his
SLOTNAME
Island
that
Luffy
was
for
with
section
World
Category
Special
Manga
wikipedia
Wiki
Encyclopedia
are
Japanese
this
Anime
SBS
Vol
page
BEGIN
END
Help
Wikia
Blue
Crew
from
User
Buggy
Straw
Portrait
Grand
him
Pirate
New
Template
Marines
they
not
Hat
Devil
FLUSH
TOP
BOXAD
Navibox
Monkey
their
Crocodile
Down
Page
Start
Shanks
have
Shichibukai
all
has
Canon
Rules
wikia
AllPages
Fruit
Zoro
Beli
Sea
name
when
Image
one
Usopp
Battle
Government
Guidelines
Random`

Comment: Why do you need to remove ascii ? You may use base64 encoding `print base64.b64encode(decoded)` to clear all 'non-ascii' characters in your decoded string

Comment: because the output of all the decoded strings in the terminal will show me the answer in a paragraph form

Comment: I think that converting the output into Ascii then exclude everything above 127 or non-numerical characters might work but I have no Idea how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

def evaluate_string_is_ascii(mystring):
    is_full_ascii=True
    for c in mystring:
        try:
            if ord(c)>0 and ord(c)<=127:
                #print c,"strict ascii =KEEP"
                pass
            elif ord(c)>127  and ord(c)<=255:
                #print c,"extended ascii code =TRASH"
                is_full_ascii=False
                break
            else:
               # print c,"no ascii  =TRASH"
                is_full_ascii=False
                break
        except:
            #print c,"no ascii  =TRASH"
            is_full_ascii=False
            break
    return is_full_ascii


my_text_content="""azertwxcv
123456789
456dqsdq13
o@��nS��?t#�
lkjal�
kfldjkjl&é"""

for line in my_text_content.split('\n'):

    #check if line contain only ascii
    if evaluate_string_is_ascii(line)==True:

        #print the line
        print line
```

Comment: your code works very well, but what I want is to not print the line which contains non-ascii characters, so if the `decoded` string contains non-ascii character it won't be printed

Comment: Is it ok now ? You may reuse `evaluate_string_is_ascii(mystring)` function in your own code like this : `if evaluate_string_is_ascii(decoded)==True:` `print decoded+"\n"`

Comment: It is a pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove non ascii characters like this : 
  EDIT : updated with the decode first.

```
output = 'string with some non-ascii characters��@$���9�HK��F�23 some more char'
output = output.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: I get an error with this output   `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 28, in <module>
    decoded = decoded.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 0):

```
if six.PY2:
    if isinstance(input_data, str):
        input_data = input_data.decode('ascii', 'ignore').encode('ascii')
    else:
        input_data = input_data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
else:
    six.PY3
    input_data = str(input_data)

print(input_data)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!